# latex-electric-env-pair-mode in AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, latex, elisp, auctex

the guys of the plain tex-mode have [added](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/NEWS.24.2) a very nice feature with emacs 24.1, a minor mode called *latex-electric-env-pair-mode* which keeps existing `\begin{...} [...] \end{...}` pairs matched. I.e. when changing the environment name in the `\begin{...}` tag, its corresponding `\end{...}` is changed automatically (very nice when changing from starred to non-starred version of an environment and vice-versa).

However, when comparing with AUCTeX, the tex-mode still sucks... but I really like the new minor mode. I have tried to make a stand-alone minor mode by copying everything that looked like it was used from tex-mode.el to a new file and changed all the descriptors (so they won't conflict with AUCTeX or any remainders for tex-mode). Unfortunately this won't work, the minor mode can be turned on but it is broke: nothing is happening.

I'm not a (e)lisp programmer, that is to say I don't really understand the code. But maybe someone likes the feature of this minor mode and can port it to a stand-alone version?
Also there might be some package out there which provides similar/equal functionality?

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Why is it everyone says AUCTeX is so much better than regular tex-mode?  Regular tex-mode does everything I want, the last time I looked at it AUCTeX only appeared to change all the keystrokes that are already wired into my fingers, and add a bunch of "insert this" keystrokes that I would never use (it's faster for me to type them out by hand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably missed `tex-env-mark` (which sets marks that are used later by `latex-electric-env-pair-mode` to find environment starters/enders) or `latex-syntax-propertize-rules` (which runs `tex-env-marks` on relevant parts of the buffer) or the setting of `syntax-propertize-function` (which uses `latex-syntax-propertize-rules` so that these rules are actually used).

BTW, rather than copying those things, I recommend you try something like the untested code below:

```
(defconst my-latex-syntax-propertize-function
   (with-temp-buffer (latex-mode) syntax-propertize-function))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'syntax-propertize-function)
                 my-latex-syntax-propertize-function)
            (latex-electric-env-pair-mode 1)))
```

Comment: I tried that but it does not work. The *Messages* buffer remarks: **File mode specification error: (void-variable latex-syntax-propertize-rules)**  Indeed I forgot the latex-syntax-propertize-rules part in my copy&rename attempt, however, when including those parts AUCTeX stops working correctly... So I guess your proposed solution (when fixed) is my best bet.

Comment: Also, I checked the value of the syntax-propertize-function (after enabling the electric-env-pair-mode with your fix) using C-h v: it is nil. I appears that the latex-syntax-propertize-rules variable is not set when using only a (require 'tex-mode) statement and thus it can not be applied, right?

Comment: Duh, you're right `latex-syntax-propertize-rules` is only set during compilation of tex-mode.  I'll update my untested recipe.

Comment: Still not working but at least `syntax-propertize-function` is no longer nil. I posted its value at pastebin ( http://pastebin.com/sdzDrr0C ), maybe you understand it. To me it looks like byte-code or something similar...

Comment: @elemakil: yes, it's byte-code, and that's normal.  As for why it doesn't work... Can you check the presence of the marks set by `tex-env-mark`?

Comment: I have experimented a little further and found out that it works partially. When I create the environment via AUCTeX (i.e. I don't write the `begin` and `end` tags myself it won't work until I edit the content of the `end` tag manually. Once I do that it works (for that pair of `begin`/`end`. I guess that is a limitation by `latex-mode` itself (probably because either it doesn't allow automatic insertion of environments or has a post-insertion hook [or something like that]). Maybe it is possible to add that kind of "hook" to the AUCTeX insertion functions by advising them to do so?

Comment: Also, when I type the `begin`/`end` pair manually it works in the same way: I have to edit the `end` tag's content and suddenly it works.  [To clarify: The first edit done in the `end` tag is performed to the corresponding `begin` tag as well; afterwards any edit done to both tags is mirrored on the other tag]. I don't know whether that is an intended behaviour, a bug in the usage without `tex-mode` or a bug in `tex-mode` but it is note the behaviour I expected.